# JSF onchange and then save

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a text box. As soon as the user clicks outside of the text box, the code below calls doSomethingOnValueChange. And things work as expected. On the other hand, if the user edits my textbox and directly clicks on save, the save method gets called first and doSomethingOnValueChange gets called later. How can I fix this?

```
 <ui:define name="label">My Text box</ui:define>
 <h:inputText required="true" value="#{myBean.myTextBox}" 
    immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{controller.doSomethingOnValueChange}">
      <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" />         
 </h:inputText>

 <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{controller.save}" />
```

Comment: what happens if you get rid of immediate?

Comment: Getting rid of immediate=true doesn't help.

Comment: With this construct, the value change listener should be called twice when you immediately press the button. Once by a synchronous request fired by the botton and once by ajax fired by the change event. Is it really called only once?

Comment: My save method was re-directing to another page. Now when remove the re-direct, I get the could not acquire lock on @Synchronized component: myController.

Comment: When I run without debug, I see that my value changed liustener gets called twice. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't have a RF3+Seam playground at hands, wo I can't guarantee if it works, but you could try to ajax-enable the `<h:commandButton>` as well (e.g. make it `<a4j:commandButton>` instead), this way the ajax events are queued and the redirect on the action method should block all events waiting in the queue. At least, it works that way in RF4 and JSF2.

Comment: i just tried it on richfaces 3.3.1 and it works as expected. <a4j:support> is unnecesary in this case anyway.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. The difference being, even if I don't click on any other button, but move to another text field, which has a4j:support onchange event associated with it in similar manner, then at times the ajax request is not even generated. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

try using `onkeyup` event, that would fix it

```
 <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onkeyup" />
```

Comment: @user238021 - the `valueChangeListener` as you described is behaving like fired only `onblur` event. So you should better change the concept using `a4j:jsFunction` calling jsfunction `onchange` event of input text.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="p" value="#{myBean.myTextBox}" />
</f:metadata>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
  {
  var x=document.getElementById("form:text").value;
  return x;
  }
</script>



<h:inputText required="true" id="text"
            valueChangeListener="#{controller.doSomething}" >
            <a4j:param noEscape="true" value="getValue()" name="p" />
            <a4j:ajax event="change" />
        </h:inputText>

    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{controller.save}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I added requestDelay="30" to my save button. Changed the button to a4j button. That fixed my issue. I also added Global queue in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.richfaces.queue.global.enabled</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how adding the delay to the save button will help in execution of onchange event?